# What is wrong with my program? it doesnt show up

Tags: python

I am supposed to modify a program so that the loop stops after 3 iterations. It was a non terminating loop before, but I changed it and now it doesn't show up at all. can you see what I did wrong?

```
i = 1

while_iterations = 1

while (i <= 3):
    print("Starting while iteration number", while_iterations)
    for number in range(5, 10):

        if (number % 2 == 1):
            print("Found an odd number: ", number)
        else:
            print(number, "is not an odd number")
        print("End of for loop.")
        print()
    while_iterations = while_iterations + 1
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Please fix your indentations using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12523564/edit) button under your answer.

Comment: I think you forgot to do i = i + 1. :)

Comment: @emiljho, where do i put it? i tried putting it in differnt places but i keep getting errors

Comment: I believe you are not just new to python, but programming as a whole. It is good thing to start programming lessons with python.http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/ 
is the best place to learn python. And considering your comments and the queston it maybe difficult at first. But one week is more than enough to get you moderately proficient in python. 
Try not to jump into coding as soon as you see a question. Good programmers do not think while coding, they foresee almost every aspect of what they are supposed to do before getting hold of the keyboard. ;)

Comment: @emiljho haha yea you are right. this is the first programming class i took and the teacher expects you to know a lot more than you should. but i will check out your website! thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your loop doesn't run because `i = 1` and the condition is `while( i > 3 )` which means it evaluates to false and skips the entire loop.

**EDIT**:

```
while_iterations = 1

while (while_iterations <= 3):
    print("Starting while iteration number", while_iterations)
    for number in range(5, 10):
        if (number % 2 == 1):
            print("Found an odd number: ", number)
        else:
            print(number, "is not an odd number")
        print("End of for loop.")
        print()
    while_iterations = while_iterations + 1
```

There, this loop terminates. You don't need two index variables, while_iterations was enough.

Comment: i changed it to (i <= 3) and it original problem is back, it keeps going on non terminating

Comment: That's not surprising, again the condition is i > 3, does the value of i ever change?

Comment: doesnt the i less that or equal than 3 fits the i=1 rule at top? sorry im new at python

Comment: once the code inside the loop is executed the condition (in this case i > 3) is re-evaluated, and then the code is executed and this goes on until the condition evaluates to false. If i never changes the loop is infinite.

Comment: @atmatm did you forget to do i=i+1?

Comment: @Marcus you mean i=i +1 at the very top?

Comment: @atmatm, no, in the loop. I think you're mixing up the `i` and `while_iterations`.

Comment: @Marcus so instead of the while_iterations after the comma in line 4, i should have print('starting while iteration number', i=i+1)

Comment: @atmatm, yes, either `i` or `while_iterations`, but not both.

Comment: now i get syntax error.. unless i misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: `print("Starting while iteration number", while_iterations)`?

Comment: @marcus i think i fixed what you said, i placed the i=i+1 under the for loop.

Comment: @atmatm, no, not there, try to replace all while_iterations to i?

Answer (score 0):

It is stuck in an infinite loop because the condition `while (i <= 3):` is always `True` because you never modify `i` after initially setting it to `1`. Try changing the condition to:

`while (while_iterations <= 3):`

Or you can remove `while_iterations` and replace all references to it with `i`.